# disable constraints before using pg_restore.exe

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint, restore

When I try to execute `pg_restore.exe` of a dump file from a database, it throws dozens of errors, all the same:

`ERROR: insert or update on table "someTable" violates foreign key constraint "aConstraintName"`

This is obviously due to the fact that I've emptied the data base before restoring it from the dump file (this file comes from a production database)... then of course no foreign keys constraint can be ok if one referenced table is empty...

Is there a way to disable the constraints and all foreign keys, for all tables, before I call `pg_restore.exe`, and afterwards, re-enable the constraints and foreign keys.

In SO I found something interesting: [deferring constraint checking to commit time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679854/postgresql-disabling-constraints).
But I don't think I can call `pg_restore.exe` from inside `psql.exe` after deferring the constraints.

There is also [this post](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2003-03/msg01387.php), dating back 10 years ago, suggesting to drop then re-add the constraints. Or to change the value of pg_class reltriggers to 0 and that would also be possible for constraints... but I'm afraid it is more hacking than good practice...

What do you advise, what is the best practice in this case ? Is using `pg_dump.exe` *with the `-clean` flag* creates a dump that bypasses the constraints checking when restoring the database ?

Comment: Cross-posted here, in case anyone finds this later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093654/is-there-a-safe-way-to-modify-the-table-pg-constraint-so-as-no-more-checking-be#comment16180853_12093654

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Have you tried the `--disable-triggers` option to `pg_restore`?

Per the documentation: *Use this if you have referential integrity checks or other triggers on the tables that you do not want to invoke during data reload.*

Please note that this only is valid for a `--data-only` restore and requires the `--superuser=username` option to be passed, as well.

Comment: And it works like a charm...